# URLs in Google Web Index Has Dropped to 0!! Why?

Tags: seo, google

Does anyone know why my website's URLs in Google web index has dropped to "0" ? It shows I have +350 link on my xml file and last week I had +150 URLs in web index. I didn't do any changes to my XML file.

Comment: This belongs on Webmasters. But, you should probably give more info/context on your situation.

Comment: How are you checking this? A Google search? Webmasters Tools? Have you made any changes? Do you use any black hat techniques? Is your content unique? Or copied? We're gonna need to know a lot more before we can help you.

Comment: Assuming by "XML file" you means sitemaps.xml, that doesn't mean much of anything. Google makes [no promises](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184)(second to last paragraph) they'll crawl all the URLs contained in it. (Obviously this doesn't solve anything for you, but don't waste time thinking it's important to the question of why you seem to have dropped out of results.)

Comment: @yc01 What kind of information do you need?

Comment: @SU, Yes its sitemap.xml. You mean even thought I lost the URLs which is 0 in google webmaster, still I have all urls crawled and in the index of google?

Comment: @Jay Any context, really. Do you use Google Webmaster Tools? If so, what do the recent crawls say? Do you have any recent crawl errors? Do sites link to your site? Does your site engage in illegal activity? Does it host porn, malware, or content encouraging adultery? Etc.

Comment: @yc01, I'm using Google Webmaster Tools. My website been crawled yesterday and it had an error which was odd because I didn't change my pages and even my SITEMAP.XML file. Any way I just deleted that link and uploaded my sitemap.xml again. Now it shows no error but still url is 0. Any thought?

Comment: Did you change the site architecture that may causes duplicate contents?

Comment: I met this problem as well. I tried hard to spread out my url. But, after my effort, I found the result is pages indexed on google dropped from 40 to 0. After reading information here, I will wait my urls back. Thanks for information here.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me a few weeks ago. I redid a section of my site and then my urls and backlinks dropped to zero. I think it had to do with Google being in the middle of re-analysing my site. I waited a week and they all came back.

It may also have to do with Google's new algorithm, but that is complete speculation. I'd recommend just waiting to see if the urls come back.

Comment: Did you still get the error of 0 URL? I did redo my page and still nothing.